# Compare the two dataframes using line graph in r

Tags: r

[my_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH2zS.jpg)Data frame1

```
quarter  year   value

q1       2012   100
q3       2013   200
q4       2014   400
q4       2015   250 
q3       2014   400
```

Data frame 2

```
quarter  year   value

q1       2014   100
q3       2012   200
q4       2015   400
q4       2012   250 
q3       2015   400
```

I want to compare these two by plotting in `r`.Can you please suggest here?

*Note:* I have tried different ways,but no luck

```
plot(DF1$fy,DF1$value,
  main ="Distribution of Assets in quarters across years",
    xlab = 'years',ylab = 'vales',type='l')
```

Comment: Your data and your request are not clear, please provide a reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi,i have attached the my query by attaching picture as well.

Comment: my_query is the link for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should obtain the desired output with the following code:

```
plot(DF1$year, DF1$value, type='l', col=1)
lines(DF2$year, DF2$value, col=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both data.frames together using `dplyr::bind_rows` and then use `tidyr::expand` to fill all missing `quarter` and `year`.

Now, you can draw `line` and `point` graph together using `ggplot` as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id="Name") %>% 
  right_join(expand(., Name, year = min(year):max(year), 
                    quarter = c("q1","q2","q3","q4")), by=c("Name","quarter","year")) %>%
  unite(YearQtr, c("year","quarter"), sep=":") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YearQtr, y = value, group=Name, col = Name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
quarter  year   value
q1       2012   100
q3       2013   200
q4       2014   400
q4       2015   250 
q3       2014   400",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- read.table(text="
quarter  year   value
q1       2014   100
q3       2012   200
q4       2015   400
q4       2012   250 
q3       2015   400",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks,but i am getting xaxis values overlapped,how can i increase the x axis values.years and quarters overlapped,unable to recognise

Comment: @ADITYAKUMARPINJALA If yoy mean overlapped at `x-axis` in `RStudio` then you can zoom graph. Another option is to use `Year` in 2-digit format. Actually, I would have preferred to use `zoo::yearmon` to display yearly quarter on x-axis.